# Android - error: cannot override the final method in SherlockActivity

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I am getting this error when adding this method to my class:

```
  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
  {
      // Inflate your menu.     
      getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.share_action_provider, menu);

      // Set file with share history to the provider and set the share intent.
      MenuItem actionItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share_action_provider_action_bar);
      ShareActionProvider actionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) actionItem.getActionProvider();        

      //actionProvider.setShareHistoryFileName(ShareActionProvider.DEFAULT_SHARE_HISTORY_FILE_NAME);
      // Note that you can set/change the intent any time,
      // say when the user has selected an image.
      actionProvider.setShareIntent(createShareIntent());

      return true;
  }
```

Here is how I declare the class:

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockActivity implements ActionBar.OnNavigationListener
```

and I have this method in other projects and I dont' get that error. Would anyone know why this error started happening here?

Thanks!

Comment: So MainActivity inherits from SherlockActivity, and you get this error with your MainActivity right?  Does SherlockActivity declare onCreateOptionsMenu as final?

Comment: @Jim I am not sure how they declare it. But I have 2 other projects where this same method has no error :) So I think something else may be wrong here

Comment: In your other projects, you inherit from the same SherlockActivity and can override onCreateOptionsMenu with no problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

SherlockActivity does override that methods as final so the framework can handle itself.

To fix this, only delete the imports from Menu, MenuItems and etc.. and import from com.sherlockbar since you are overriding the correct method.

Answer (score 2):

You are likely using the wrong `Menu` class.

`SherlockActivity` overrides and finalizes the Android-standard `onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu)` method.

It also declares the (new, overloaded) method `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)`, which takes a `com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu`.